# Cannot build avahi4j: avahi4j_Client.c:18:32: fatal error: avahi-common/error.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, ant, avahi

Per the title of the post I'm trying to build avahi4j, but very quickly run into a wall after downloading: https://code.google.com/p/avahi4j/downloads/detail?name=avahi4j-0.1.tar.gz&can=2&q=

After extracting, and then executing `ant clean all` from within the avahi4j-0.1 directory, I receive the following error:

```
ant clean all
Buildfile: /home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/build.xml

clean:
     [exec] make: Entering directory `/home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/src'
     [exec] rm -f avahi4j_Client.o avahi4j_EntryGroup.o avahi4j_Avahi4JConstants.o thread-watch.o avahi4j_ServiceBrowser.o avahi4j_ServiceResolver.o avahi4j_RecordBrowser.o libavahi4j.so ./*~
     [exec] make: Leaving directory `/home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/src'
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/classes

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/classes

jnilib:
     [exec] make: Entering directory `/home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/src'
     [exec] gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include/linux/ -I/usr/include/avahi-common  -O3 -fPIC -DVER_MAJ="0" -DVER_MIN="1"   -c -o avahi4j_Client.o avahi4j_Client.c
     [exec] make: Leaving directory `/home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/src'
     [exec] avahi4j_Client.c:18:32: fatal error: avahi-common/error.h: No such file or directory
     [exec]  #include <avahi-common/error.h>
     [exec]                                 ^
     [exec] compilation terminated.
     [exec] make: *** [avahi4j_Client.o] Error 1

BUILD FAILED
/home/myUser/Downloads/avahi4j-0.1/build.xml:75: exec returned: 2 

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

EDIT: for completeness, I run the following commands, which produces the error:

```
wget https://avahi4j.googlecode.com/files/avahi4j-0.1.tar.gz
tar xzvf avahi4j-0.1.tar.gz  
cd avahi4j-0.1/
ant
ant clean all
```

Moreover, running `find . -name error.h` produces no results.

Comment: Sure - it cannot find 'avahi-common/error.h'.

Comment: FYI... Downloaded the avahi package (as per the code.google.com link supplied in the question). After extracting, ran 'ant'.  Build was successful.  Then ran 'ant clean all`, which was also successful.  Then re-ran 'ant', and build was again successful.  SUSE Linux (SLES11).  ant-1.7.1... /usr/include/avahi-common/error.h exists.

Comment: Yes, but why not? It's strange that the standard package doesn't even contain all necessary files to compile as shipped. I'm just wondering if I'm missing something basic that's not written in the README file.

Comment: @Mahonri, at what point was error.h created? Was it auto-generated by ant? I ran the same steps, and still have the same error, and `find . -name error.h` produces no results.

Comment: I did an "rpm -qf /usr/include/avahi-common/error.h" which reported "libavahi-devel-0.6.23-11.30.4".  Perhaps you need to install this package as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libavahi-devel` package installs the missing components.

To resolve the issues presented by the question install the `libavahi-devel` package.

Comment: I'm actually still getting a failure, but a different one, after following the additional instructions except for installing open jdk (we're using Oracle's jdk). The error I still get is a missing `jni.h`.